# HANA Vora not taking password from putty

Tags: vora

I have setup VORA and all the services are and cluster node are up and running while accessing vora account from putty using sudo su - vora it takes me to the vora account node which is [vora@master ~]$ now i want to login to vora account using command sudo su- it asked me for password to enter, i am entering correct password but it denied saying incorrect password always, is there any default password i have to enter here? as i have tried multiple time entering my password and it is not going through

thank,s Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command prompt indicates that you are using the Vora Developer Edition in AWS.

Once deployed, you can connect via ssh using user 'centos' and your AWS key pair, e.g.:

```
ssh -i aws_vorakeypair.pem centos@<IP>
```

Once logged on with user 'centos' you can switch to user 'root' or 'vora'. No password is needed. E.g.

```
[centos@master ~]$ sudo su -
[root@master ~]#
```

OR

```
[centos@master ~]$ sudo su - vora
[vora@master ~]$
```